# can we make record types in to read only in lightning record pages

Tags: record-type, lightning-record-page

When an SSP Services Case (RecordType=SSP Services) is closed, then all the fields should be ready-only to the users. **when status is closed**

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The general expectation here is that you've done some research and have made an honest attempt before asking a question. If you just leave your question as a list of requirements, then you'll tend to get downvotes and your question may become closed. We're all volunteering our time and knowledge here, so if you don't show us that you've made an honest attempt it's really easy for people to think that you're asking them to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The "record detail" component of a Lightning Record Page (a.k.a. a Flexipage) is controlled by the "page layout" that you've assigned to a given recordtype.

So to make the record read-only here, you'll want to:

- Make a new record type (perhaps called "Closed SSP Services")
- Make a new page layout (you can clone the existing page layout to make this step faster), and edit all the fields on the layout so they are read-only (click the wrench icon that appears on the right side when you hover over a field in the page layout editor)
- Assign the new page layout to the new record type
- And finally, create a record-triggered flow (Optimize the flow for "Fast Field Updates", a.k.a. a before-save record-triggered flow) to update the record type of a record when the status is changed

While this is more work than creating a simple validation rule, I would say that this is *the preferred way* to implement this.

A validation rule alone cannot handle stuff of the form `only allow fields X, Y, and Z to be edited` unless you check that *every other field on your SObject is not changing*. While it is technically possible for SObjects with a small number of fields, it's not practical at all.

The recordtype + page layout approach also still allows Apex, Flows, and Actions to make modifications. Additionally, people with the System Administrator profile can bypass this.
The "read only" bit is only enforced when you edit a record through the UI. That's really useful when you have (not "if", this is a matter of "when") a user that mistakenly or prematurely changes the record so it becomes read-only and it needs to be changed back.